# how to make an HDD live as long as possible on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, hard-drive, samba, backup, raspberrypi

I got myself a Raspi with an Ubuntu Server OS on it and I use it for several applications.

Usually I use it for testing or experiments and education, but I had an idea to put an external HDD on it and use it as a Backup Folder I can always use (so if I need a file from this HDD I can just copy it or if I want to backup stuff I can back it up to the HDD).

Now I’m worried that the HDD will be working continuously and may have reduced life because it’s in 24/7 use.

My Question is if it’s possible to have the HDD turn itself off and on whenever it’s needed.

My Raspi is a Raspberry Pi 4b with 4GB RAM; the HDD is a WD Elements Portable 5TB.

I’ve heard about hdd´s going into standby mode, but I want a sure way to maximise the device’s longevity.

Comment: A portable drive is arguably the worse choice for something like a server that may well be up 24/7 to be useful.

Comment: other option would have been an internal hdd with an adapter, and they needed some extra electricity. But after looking out on the web alot said it is an bad idea because of heat, electricity, sound, etc. and they recommend an external HDD which dont have all these "cons". Would it be rly that bad for te HDD if it runs in that server, also if i want to try it with the method of automatically turning off ?

Comment: It kind of helped me. The hdparm command is for intern and not extern hdd, but that got me to an another programm called "hd-idle" which sets external Hard Drives into Stand by after 10 minutes. I will test it out to check if its rly work and tell u my result

Comment: @mikewhatever i tested hd-idle and it were sucessfull! i can set the idle time how i want and thats what i searched for. Ty for ur hint.